# Create parent class reference to child class instance resulting from implicit cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, reference

Is there a way for a compiler to perform an implicit conversion *and* reference the result
via a reference to the parent class of the conversion result? Concretely, I'd like for this to work:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

struct C : public A {
    C() = default;
    C(B const& b) {}  // Without this line the compiler can't cast B->C
};

struct D : public A {
    D(A const& input) {}
    // explicit D(C const& input) {} // Adding this makes everything work, but I'd like to avoid it.
};

int main () {
    // Obviously works
    A a{};
    D d1{a};
    // Also works because A const& can refer to c
    C c{};
    D d2{c};
    // Similarly, a reference to C (which is actually a B) is acceptable
    B b{};
    C const& c2{b};
    D d3{c2};
    // Forcing the cast also works.
    D d4{static_cast<C const&>(b)};
    // I want this to work without defining the second constructor for D.
    // D d5{b}; 
};
```

The final commented out line of my example will not compile without also defining a constructor (made explicit to clearly avoid any casting) for `D` from a `C`. However, b is implicitly convertible to a C, which can then be passed to the `D(A const&)` constructor, so in principle there's a valid code path to follow here. I know that the standard only allows a single implicit conversion (12.3/4), but viewing an object as a reference to its parent class shouldn't fall under that umbrella. Is there a way to get the final line of code (construction of a `D` from a `B`) to work without making `D` constructible from a reference to `C`? If not, what is the relevant language restriction preventing that?

For context, in my use case `D` should be possible to construct from any subclass of its parent `A`. I now want to make it possible to transparently parse certain types that are not subclasses of `A` by implicitly casting them to a suitable corresponding subclass of `A`. Forcing users to add the static cast as in the second to last line of code makes for a less pleasant API since users can no longer treat `B` as something that can be coerced to a subclass of `A` and they have to know that `C` exists, which I'd like to avoid. Conversely, I want to avoid defining the second constructor because that mucks up the inheritance structure: `D` shouldn't have to actually know what those subclasses are.

Comment: The short answer is "no". The longer answer goes like that. Suppose you get your code working as you want. Imagine now that  someone adds another class C1 with the exact same interface as C, also derived from A, also having a conversion from B. Now which one should be selected? So just by adding a new class C1, someone breaks existing code. Adding a brand new entity with a brand new name should never break existing code.

Comment: To allow `D` to be constructible from classes it has no prior knowledge of, define a templated constructor. I assume given the question you know how to turn that into a subclass of `A` (i.e. you know what `C` should be for any given type `B`), so you can perform the `static_cast` within  within the constructor initialization. However, note that you have potential lifetime problems: casting to a `const C&` involves constructing a temporary `C` and referencing it. You have to be very careful about that temporary's lifetime. Doing the cast within the constructor will run into this.